# Is there locational damage in Postal 2?

Tags: postal-2

I haven't noticed any difference in damage between head and legs, for example.

From [GameSpot's review](http://www.gamespot.com/reviews/postal-2-review/1900-6025142/):

> According to the game's documentation, Postal 2 supports a locational
>   damage system, but it's spotty at best. A bullet to the head rarely
>   appears to do more damage than a shot to the leg.

Comment: It doesn't look like it. The tutorial for mods on the Running with Scissors site mentions a "HitLocation" variable, but it seems to be a vector indicating the point of impact for a projectile.

Comment: @SeanDuggan: You could post as an answer, add a source for the mod tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be locational damage. The [tutorial for adding a new weapon through mods](http://www.runningwithscissors.com/Basic%20Weapon%20Changes.htm) on the Running with Scissors site has the modder override the "ProcessTouch" function which is used to determine behavior when striking an Actor.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Explode on contact with anything!
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
simulated function ProcessTouch(Actor Other, Vector HitLocation)
{
    GenExplosion(HitLocation,Normal(HitLocation-Other.Location), Other);
}
```

As you can see, `HitLocation` is a vector, not a location where the [Actor](https://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Legacy:Actor_Class_Hierarchy_(P2)) was hit. There simply is no code to check for locational damage.

There are console commands, and mods, to enable headshots again as discussed [in this Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/223470/discussions/0/558755530612334817/) and [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/app/223470/discussions/0/530645446305624317/). I suspect that they [turn on `bCanHeadShoot` on the weapons](https://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Legacy:EnhancedItems/EnhancedWeapon).

> It is very clear what he was posting; heatshots with certain weapons do not grant an instant kill.
>
> 1. Open your console by pressing < º >, < ñ > or < ~ > (depending on your keyboard language).
> 2. Enter "sissy" (without quotes).
> 3. Enter "headshots" (without quotes)
> 4. Now every headshot will kill anyone.

....

> There's a mod that pretty much does this